# Indexing another data frame in R

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe

You have one data frame for class of animal:

```
animal <- data.frame('code' = c(1:4), 'class' = c('mammal','bird','fish','lizard'))
```

Output:

```
code  animal
  1    mammal
  2     bird
  3     fish
  4    lizard
```

You have another data frame showing the land speed of the animals based on the code:

```
land.speed <- data.frame('speed' = c('42','32','6','0','100'), 'code' = c(1,2,4,3,1))
```

Output:

```
speed code
  42    1
  32    2
   6    4
   0    3
 100    1
```

What I would like to do is create a new column in the second data frame titled 'animal' based on the code value from the first data frame.

Example:

```
speed code animal
  42    1  mammal
  32    2   bird
   6    4  lizard
   0    3   fish
 100    1  mammal
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
animal <- data.frame('code' = c(1:4), 'class' = c('mammal','bird','fish','lizard'))
land.speed <- data.frame('speed' = c('42','32','6','0','100'), 'code' = c(1,2,4,3,1))
out <- merge(land.speed, animal, by = "code", all.x = TRUE)
out
#   code speed  class
# 1    1    42 mammal
# 2    1   100 mammal
# 3    2    32   bird
# 4    3     0   fish
# 5    4     6 lizard
```

What this does is takes your `land.speed` data frame and merges on the `animal` dataframe by matching the `code` variable. Assuming that this is a simplified version of your real data frames, and therefore more columns are sure to be included, you should look into the `by.x`, `by.y`, `all.x`, `all.y`, and `all` parameters of `merge` to fit your specific needs.

Comment: This worked great, thank you for your help. Do you know why it reorders the data?

Comment: Yeah, it reorders based on the variable(s) that you matched on. I'm not super familiar with the algorithm for merge, but I presume that it works through the matching variable in the first data frame looking for matches in the second data frame. So, to improve efficiency, it first sorts the data frames by the matching variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge` function

```
result<-merge(x=animal,y=land.speed,by="code",all=TRUE)
```

**Output**:

```
  code  class speed
1    1 mammal    42
2    1 mammal   100
3    2   bird    32
4    3   fish     0
5    4 lizard     6
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `match`.  It should be faster

```
land.speed$animal <- animal$class[match(land.speed$code, animal$code)]
land.speed
#  speed code animal
#1    42    1 mammal
#2    32    2   bird
#3     6    4 lizard
#4     0    3   fish
#5   100    1 mammal
```

Or if we have matching 'code' elements in both datasets

```
land.speed$animal <- animal$class[land.speed$code]
```